# Как завершить несколько потоков?

Tags: многопоточность, java

Здравствуйте. В коде программы хочу запустить параллельно и последовательно потоки. Это мне удалось, но не удается приостановить их. Подскажите, что нужно изменить. Заранее спасибо!

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package testactionevent;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author
 */
public class TestActionEvent extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private JButton jbtStart = new JButton("Start");
    private JButton jbtStop = new JButton("Stop");
    SiThread first;
    SiThread second;
    SiThread third;
    SiThread fourth;
    SiThread fifth;

    public TestActionEvent() {
        first = new SiThread();
        second = new SiThread();
        third = new SiThread();
        fourth = new SiThread();
        fifth = new SiThread();

        setTitle("TestActionEvent");

        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        getContentPane().add(jbtStart);
        getContentPane().add(jbtStop);

        jbtStart.addActionListener(this);
        jbtStop.addActionListener(this);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestActionEvent frame = new TestActionEvent();
        frame.setTitle("Two buttons");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(900, 900);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == jbtStart) {

            Thread thread1 = new Thread(first);
            thread1.start();

            Thread thread2 = new Thread(second);
            Thread thread3 = new Thread(second);
            thread2.start();
            thread3.start();
            try {
                thread2.join();
                thread3.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestActionEvent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            Thread thread4 = new Thread(first);
            thread4.start();
            try {
                thread4.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestActionEvent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }

            Thread thread5 = new Thread(first);
            thread5.start();
            try {
                thread5.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(TestActionEvent.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        } else if (e.getSource() == jbtStop) {
            first.stop();

            second.stop();
            third.stop();
            fourth.stop();
            fifth.stop();

        }

    }
}

class SiThread implements Runnable {
    boolean lopend = false;

    public void run() {
        lopend = true;
        while (lopend) {
            try {

                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            for (int i = 0; i <= 20; i++) {

                System.out.println(i);
                if (i == 20) {
                    System.out.println("zakinchuvsi");

                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        lopend = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: в приведеном куске кода у вас точно нет ошибки в строчке н2 ?

    Thread thread2 = new Thread(second);
    Thread thread3 = new Thread(second);
    thread2.start();
    thread3.start();

Comment: в приведеном куске кода у вас точно нет ошибки в строчке н2 ?
Thread thread2 = new Thread(second);
Thread thread3 = new Thread(second);
thread2.start();
thread3.start();

Извините дествительно.

Comment: `stop()` не забудьте декларировать как `synchronized`

Answer (score 1):

Неправильно написаны названия цифр на английском. А еще ты запускаешь одни потоки, а останавливаешь другие.

Comment: Я немогу понять почему один поток можно остановить, а несколько нельзя. Хотел вставить код с одним потоком, только не хватает
коментария.

Comment: редактируй вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Использование методов stop и resume не рекомендуется. Лучше в методе run в цикле while сделайте проверку на прерывание, например так

```
while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
```

а потоки убить так

```
second.interrupt();
```